# highlight div on page load?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to highlight a div on page load. i could find a solution.
 But the issue is that it fades out entire content of the div. what i used

```
$('#searchdiv .highligth').fadeOut(1000);
```

and the html i have written

```
                   <div id="searchdiv">
                    <div class="highligth">
                        <table cellspacing="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="anchorText">Filter By:</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objLanguage" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
                                        SelectMethod="GetLanguage" TypeName="Lang.Repositories.LanguageRepository">
                                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dlFilter" runat="server" DataSourceID="objLanguage" DataTextField="LanguageType"
                                        DataValueField="LanguageId" Width="150px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" OnDataBinding="dlFilter_DataBinding"
                                        OnDataBound="dlFilter_DataBound">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnFilter" runat="server" Width="90px" Text="Filter" OnClick="btnFilter_Click" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

for few seconds the div is highlighted and as fadeout is mentioned so the content also fade out and the div becomes empty.
How to let those control be visible??

Thanks.

Comment: Well of course it would fade out the entire contents of the div, what exactly are you trying to achieve here? Be more specific.

Comment: Do you want to just animate and change the opacity?

Comment: Can you post the content of the .highlight CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fadeOut and fadeIn method,

```
 $('#searchdiv .highligth').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(2000);
```

View Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rgVTW/

Comment: I think this will do. And i have not vote it down. :-) Your solution is better as i not changing any color n all.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking to do?

```
 $('.highligth').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Comment: i tried your code. but i don't see any effect. and i just wanted to hightlight the div for few second but with animation like fadeout. and css for the .highligth{ background-color:White;}

Comment: `highlight` changes the background of the DIV to a yellow-ish green and then fades it out according to the `duration`; here 3000 (3 seconds.)

Comment: i did see the document but when i wrote your code but it didn't show any effect. so only i wrote that. looks like i need to add the css file <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: Put the code within `$(document).ready(function(){ ...(hightlight code)... });`

Comment: ok i tried your code with fresh page. i am pasting my code which i tried.

Comment: Doesnt work.i tried this .<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com......"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/../..css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
     .highligth { background: red; width:300px; height:100px;}
    </style>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('.highligth').effect("highligth", {}, 3000);
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div class="highligth">
           Hello Worlds
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#searchdiv .highligth').css({opacity: 0}).animate({opacity: 0.5 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a very easy and new way to do this.

just add `#:~:text=Highlight%20These`

try accessing this link

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588721#:~:text=Highlight%20a%20text`